# docker push to private registry failed "server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"

Tags: docker, docker-registry

just follow the [doc from dockerhub](https://docs.docker.com/registry/):
because my docker is installed by snap, so I edit:

- `sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json`
- `sudo vi /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json`
- `sudo vi /var/snap/docker/current/etc/docker/daemon.json`
  [image: failed msg]

[image]

any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: from your picture code snippet, it looks like you didn't restart the docker service after twiking the daemon.json file

Comment: I have restart many times...but my docker is installed by snap, Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4, is this the cause?

Comment: from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907110/docker-snap-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-o) thread it looks like it could pose an issue for docker, could you try using `apt` instead? [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-future-of-the-docker-snap/7218/32) snap forum thread stops after April 2019 with no change for the better

Answer (score 4):

after I refer [snap docker daemon.json path](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299677/809566)
edit these files:

```
sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
sudo vi /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json
sudo vi /var/snap/docker/current/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

It works, thank you!